# how to display whitespace characters.. but omit when text is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

### Setup:

I'd like to output some text that shows visible spaces, linebreaks, etc
(For the purpose of displaying strings for debug purposes (or for say a rich-text editor))
ie, id like to make the following type of substitutions

```
" " -> "<span class="whitespace">&middot;</span>"  
"\r" -> "<span class="whitespace">\\r</span>"  
"\n" -> "<span class="whitespace">\\n</span>"
```

perhaps  the following CSS rule could be defined

```
/*display whitespace chars as a light grey*/
.whitespace { color:#CCC; }
```

so that

> this two line
>       string

would be displayed as

> this·two·lined\n
>   \t   string

---

### The Question:

Is it possible so that when the above "visual-whitepace" text is selected / copied-to-clipboard... it copies without the whitespace markup?

Is there some CSS property to display x, but copy y?
javascript hack?
special whitespace-font?
other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<style>.paragraph-marker:after { content: "\B6" }</style>

<p>Foo<span class="paragraph-marker"></span></p>

<p>Bar<span class="paragraph-marker"></span></p>
```

The `:after` is a "pseudo-selector" which matches a pseudo-node that immediately follows the affected element.

The [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/content) property can be used with these pseudo-nodes to specify the textual content of them.  It comes in handy when specifying quotation marks before and after quoted sections, or list separators like commas in semantic HTML `<ol>` which you don't want to display in bullet format.

It should come in handy for your use case since browsers don't deal with pseudo-nodes when converting a DOM selection stored in the clipboard to plain text on paste.

Comment: Not enough JavaScript!... just kidding :)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, You're right.  I forgot the `<script src="job-security.js?web=3.0&social=true&cloud=abused&gamified=11"></script>`

Comment: the CSS rules I came up with:
.ws_s, .ws_t, .ws_r, .ws_n, .ws_p { color:#666; }  
.ws_s { margin-right:-.5em; }  
.ws_s:before{ content: "\B7";  font-weight:bold; } /* &middot; */  
.ws_t:before { content: "\203A"; } /* &rsaquo; */  
.ws_r:before { content: "\\r"; }
.ws_n:before { content: "\\n"; }  
.ws_p:after { content: "\B6" } /* &para; */

Comment: @BradKent, Cool.  If you add `@media print { .ws_s, .ws_t { color: #000 } }` then you can ensure that high-contrast is used for printing.

Answer (score 2):

http://codepen.io/msvbg/pen/ebgrj

Works fine in the latest version of Chrome. Flip the `showWhitespace` variable to try it both ways. It works by sticking a visible whitespace layer underneath the text layer, and only the top-most layer is copied by default.